# Keep getting the same result from my rock paper scissors computer duel

Tags: python

I'm trying an experiment where two AIs duel each other in rock paper scissors and learn from the matches. I used pyplot to plot the graph for their victory counts as long the 10000 round game goes, but I kept getting this same result. Is there an issue in my logic?

This same plot keeps appearing every time even though I used numpy's randint function:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def playrps(p1,p2):

    l1 = ['r','p','s']
    l2 = ['p','s','r']

    l3 = ['s','r','p']

    for i in range(3) :

        if p1.play == l1[i] and p2.play == l2[i]:

            p2.victory += 1
            p1.victory -= 1

            p1.sett.append(l3[i])
            p2.sett.append(l2[i])

        elif p2.play == l1[i] and p1.play == l2[i]:

            p1.victory += 1
            p2.victory -= 1

            p1.sett.append(l2[i])
            p2.sett.append(l3[i])

class player:
        victory = 0
        play = None
        sett = []

rps = ['r','p','s']

p1 = player()
p1.sett = rps
p2 = player()
p2.sett = rps

p1.play = p1.sett[rd.randint(len(p1.sett))]
p2.play = p2.sett[rd.randint(len(p2.sett))]

a1 = []
a2 = []

for i in range(1000):
    rd.seed = i
    a1.append(p1.victory)
    a2.append(p2.victory)

    playrps(p1,p2)


plt.plot(a1)
plt.plot(a2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are only choosing random moves before the loop, but then simulating 1000 games with the same moves; and there is also a problem because you made `sett` a class variable so all `player` instances share the same list.

Comment: DON'T RE-SEED THE RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR INSIDE THE LOOP!  Seeding the random number generator only needs to be run one time in the app.

Comment: What is the Ai supposed to learn? Predicting a random choice? That's not possible, unless your random number generator is flawed. "Learning" to play a game means choosing an action based on observations, but there's nothing to observe in rock-paper-scissors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the part in which the players select their move inside the loop.
At the moment the selection is only made once for all the 1000 games.

```
for i in range(1000):
    p1.play = p1.sett[rd.randint(len(p1.sett))]
    p2.play = p2.sett[rd.randint(len(p2.sett))]
    a1.append(p1.victory)
    a2.append(p2.victory)

    playrps(p1,p2)
```